# Mockmvc put method is not working spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockito

I am writing test cases for my spring restful services. We have a put service in the controller, the syntax is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody List<PaidUpResponse> updateStatus(
       @RequestBody @Valid PaidUpRequest paidUpRequest,
       HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
}
```

to write test case, I used the following method

```
mockMvc.perform(put("/update").contentType(UnitTestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(UnitTestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(request)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

but it is giving compilation error, saying 
"The method put(String) is undefined". could you suggest me how to test put method?

Comment: Check Type of your mockMvc Object. How do you instantiate this Object ? Normally the call of this method is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to import the appropriate dependency:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.put;
```

or

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Evil Toad, it is working. thanks alot.